# What is the effect of earth's speed on flight?

Tags: airspeed

What happens if an object (plane or space ship) travels at a speed less than that of earth rotation?

Comment: *"What happens if an object (plane or space ship) travels at a speed less than that of earth rotation"* Since the earths rotation has almost no effect, nothing. Same as getting in your car and driving. (Unless you are talking about a space ship *in space*?)

Comment: Speeds must be measured against some frame of reference. It's difficult to understand what is yours, hence to understand what *speed less than Earth rotation* means. Think about differences between equator and pole, or if you travel along a meridian for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The stationary plane and the atmosphere were already moving at the speed of Earth's rotation. Because of this, the Earth's rotational speed really has very little effect on aircraft speed. To answer the second part of your question, almost all passenger jets fly slower than the Earth's rotation. The Earth rotates at 1675 km/hr at the equator; average cruise speed is 878-926 km/hr.

Comment: *Earth rotates at 1675 km/hr*: ohh, at North pole too? Earth rotates at 15° per hour about the pole axis, and at 360° per year around the Sun..

Comment: I often fly Polar routes between Canada and Asia. Some of these flights take us westbound over Alaska at 900 km/hr, and we often fly faster than the earth rotates at those latitudes.  Sometimes I will see the sun set in the west, and then rise in the west, as we fly westbound.